# excel timer macro not working, "macro can't be found or macros not enabled"

Tags: vba, excel, macros

So I've built this timer macro that more than one youtube person has specified how to build in this exact same way, but it still refuses to work.

```
Sub StartTimer()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "nextTime"
End Sub

Sub nextTime()
    If Sheet1.Range("I1") = 0 Then Exit Sub
    End If
    Range("I1").Value = Range("I1").Value - TimeValue("00:00:01")
    StartTimer
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "nextTime", , False
End Sub
```

The problem arises in the line of code within the StartTimer Subroutine. The nextTime method simply does not get recognized, as the Error says:
    The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be     disabled. This is obviously not the case as all of my other macros work, and the subroutine is right there. What are your suggestions?

Comment: How do you try to run the macro?

Comment: It may be a name conflict. Is something other than the sub also named `nextTime`? For example the error will occur if a module is also named `nextTime`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create a countdown timer in excel 2010 using VBA (excel)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37173026/create-a-countdown-timer-in-excel-2010-using-vba-excel)  (I wish I had noticed that **before** I answered.)

Comment: Have a look at: http://docs.chejunkie.com/measure-performance-vba/

Answer (score 2):

Move your code out of the worksheet code module and put it into a normal code module.

Alternatively, you could call it by fully qualifying it as `Sheet1.nextTime` (where `Sheet1` needs to be the worksheet code name where the code resides), but I think it is probably better to put it into the project level code module.

You also need to remove the `End If` from the `nextTime` subroutine.

And you need to fix the `StopTimer` routine to pass the correct time - i.e. the time at which the next event is due to run.

```
Public nextRunTime As Date
Sub StartTimer()
    nextRunTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime nextRunTime, "nextTime"
End Sub

Sub nextTime()
    If Sheet1.Range("I1") = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Range("I1").Value = Range("I1").Value - TimeValue("00:00:01")
    StartTimer
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
    Application.OnTime nextRunTime, "nextTime", , False
End Sub
```

Comment: The sheet1.nexTime thing worked perfectly. Thank you for your time. I'm very new to vba, so I will be trying out your advice as well.